# Android Zxing ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, zxing

This is my first android app, so I could be getting everything completely wrong.  I'm a C# by nature and I'm interpreting the error message below to the equivalent of a missing void in a dll.  But I've tried to find every example I can, and I cannot figure out how to get this to work.

I only have 1 goal, to make an android app with 1 button that when I click it starts the QR scanner in `Zxing` that doesnt require the additional app installed

but here is the error i'm getting
`04-10 21:12:15.380  30818-30818/com.example.mycomp.zxingapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN (has extras) }`

I've download https://github.com/zxing/zxing/archive/zxing-3.2.0.zip and built it using `mvn -DskipTests -Dgpg.skip=true install`.  Then I dragged and drop the .jar into my libs folder.

Here is my `activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Scan"
    android:id="@+id/scanButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="97dp" />
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
package com.example.mycomp.zxingapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private Button scan;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    scan= (Button)findViewById(R.id.scanButton);

    scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

            // Handle successful scan

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
            Log.i("App","Scan unsuccessful");
        }
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void clickButton(View v) {


    Button but = (Button)v;
    ((Button)v).setText("woot woot");
}




}
```

`build.gradle`  yes this is under `app`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mycomp.zxingapp"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

Any help is welcomed

[image: ugh]

Comment: Try this if it will work  `<activity android:name=".CaptureActivity"` .. idk if it will work, just a general, workaround

Comment: @Elltz from what I gather i'm trying to use intent and not use intent at the same time but it would be helpful if there was an actual walk through to andriod studio not using intent

Comment: Are you trying to integrate by Intent? then you need none of this https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library *core-3.2.0.jar* is for **decoding** only, it doesn't do any of the take-a-picture-and-then-decode-and-display-result stuff. As such the Activity you are trying to initiate (*com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity*) doesn't exist in the jar file.

To do what you want to achieve you'll need to extract and modify the code in ***/zxing-zxing-3.2.0/android***, that's where *com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity* and all the support classes it uses resides. My suggestion is to import the whole thing and slowly cut away the classes you don't need.

Comment: I'd ask people to not start by cloning all of the Android app. People end up just cloning the UI, and that's not permitted.

Comment: @SeanOwen Sorry i'm not following, i'm just trying to get a working zxing app, i tried to mvn it an di get thanks for the tip.  I tried to mvn build it same was as above and I get [INFO] Generating R file for com.google.zxing:android:apk:4.7.3
[ERROR] Error when generating sources.
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: No Android SDK path could be found.